# Why do we use @Echo off/on instead of just Echo off/on?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am wondering as stated above why do we use @Echo off/on instead of Echo off/on. Is there any reason for this or just for the sake of visibility? According to this it doesn't seem to make a difference visually:

```
C:\Users\Jack> Echo Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!

C:\Users\Jack> Echo off
Echo Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!
Echo on

C:\Users\Jack> Echo Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!

C:\Users\Jack> @Echo off
Echo Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!
@Echo on

C:\Users\Jack> Echo Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `@` hides the command itself from the output. If you don't use it, there'd be no way to eliminate the command echos completely from a batch file, you'd always get the first line as output.

Answer (score 2):

From a batch file, if echo is currently on, then `@echo off` will not be echoed, whereas `echo off` will:

```
C:\working\test>type test.cmd
echo off
echo hello

C:\working\test>test

C:\working\test>echo off
hello
```

If echo is currently off, then there is no difference between `@echo on` and `echo on`; the former might be used out of habit, or because the programmer didn't want the behaviour to depend on whether echo was currently on or off.

Answer (score 0):

you hide the command with `@`
so for example:

```
echo off
echo hello
pause
```

result:

```
C:\fakepath>echo off
hello
Press any key to continue . . .
```

instead, if you use `@echo off`:
program:

```
@echo off
echo hello
pause
```

result:

```
hello
Press any key to continue . . .
```

this can actually be replaced by `@code`:

```
@echo hello
@pause
```

result:

```
hello
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: I can't see any other information nor better explanations compared to the six year old answers